# how can I power my rtx 3070ti lhr?

Tags: power-supply, gpu, pci-express

I have an rtx 3070ti LHR , it has dual 8-pin and it looks like its tdp is 290watts(I'm still searching for the right answer because some sites say 3070 needs 290watts but what I have is 3070ti). I have a **(gpu side)2x 6+2 pin cable coming from (psu side)one 8 pin** that is included in the package of my psu. Base on my shallow understanding about pcie wires, (psu side)8 pins can only produce 150 watts so my **(gpu side)2x 6+2 pin cable coming from (psu side)one 8 pin** cannot power my rtx3070ti which requires 290watts. Any help on powering this thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the exact specifications, but it's a pretty normal kind of setup to have one 8-pin connector on the psu and two 8-pin connectors on the GPU.

As long as you use the cables provided with your PSU you can connect all GPUs. At least, if the cables provide enough connectors and the overall wattage can power the configuration of your components.